# how to document function templates with `requires` clauses and `static_assert`s?

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation

If there were a `std::frobnicate` function template in the C++ standard, it might be specifed as follows:

> ```
> template <class T>
> void frobnicate(T t);
> ```
>
> *Requires:* `widget<T>` is `true`
>
> *Mandates:* `sprocket<T>` is `false`

The "Requires" says that this overload is only considered for types that satisfy the `widget` concept. It is equivalent to constraining the function with `requires widget<T>`.

The "Mandates" says that if you call `frobnicate` with a `sprocket`, the program will be ill-formed. It is equivalent to a `static_assert(!sprocket<T>)` in the body of the function.

I would like to be able to draw this distinction in my Doxygen comments. Sadly there does not appear to be any `@requires` or `@mandates` Doxygen special commands. Are there other features I can (ab)use to achieve this?

Comment: The closest I can think of right off would be [`\pre`](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdpre).

Comment: Some workarounds are posted here: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/2732

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What are the settings you are using (i.e the ones different from the default settings i.e. the result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`)?

Comment: doxygen 1.10. the settings i tweak are:

BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = YES
RECURSIVE              = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
GENERATE_XML           = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
PREDEFINED             = LEGATE_STL_DOXYGEN